# Powerbuilder OrcaScript: How to full get latest from SVN svn repository

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm trying to do full GLV but below script is unable to get changed object in my local directory.
changes are not reflecting in my local workspace.

start session
scc set connect property provider "Pushok SVNSCC" 
scc set connect property userid "xxx"
scc set connect property localprojpath ".\"
scc set connect property project "D:\Share"
scc set connect property logfile ".\MyPortableExample.log"
scc set connect property logappend "FALSE"
scc set connect property deletetempfiles "FALSE"
scc connect
scc set target ".\testtarget.pbt" "refresh_all"
scc get latest version ".\testtarget.pbt"
scc refresh target "FULL"
scc close
end session

Any one have any other suggestion to get all object from SVN.
Thanks & regard
Sudeep

Answer (score 0):

I use PBSCC which is similar to PushOK. I recommend you not try to use the SCC commands to get the latest version. Instead use svn to update the working copy and only use OrcaScript for the build. You may also want to take a look at PBOrca. It is more capable than OrcaScript. It keeps track of the objects that didn't compile and tries them again until all are compiled or nothing else compiles on a pass.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
As per my understanding, PBOrca is different from ORCA Script Right?
Can you please explore PBOrca or send me some link so I can read about it.

Regards
Sudeep